# XDocument change schema

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, linq-to-xml

I'm working on an XML validator with XSD files. The XML has to be validated with any XSD file, which means the XSD schema has to be added to the XML file, but of course the schema has to be deleted from the XML first (if it exists).
My workaround:

-I'm successfully removing the schema from the XML file with recursion.

-I'm successfully adding the XSD schema to the XML.

The problem that I have, is with the validation:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
```

/* adding/deleting schemas recursively */

```
doc.Save("temp.xml");

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("temp.xml", settings))
       doc = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```

The reason I'm using XmlReader and not the .Validate() method is that I need to highlight the actual error rows and the .Validate() method does not give me back the LineNumber from the ValidationEventHandler exception.

Is there another way to change the schema of an XML, and still validate it through lines without saving the new xml to a temp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand...in the `ValidationEventHandler` you get `ValidationEventArgs` which has an `Exception` property with `LineNumber` and `LinePosition`. Of course if you're **validating** against a schema, not checking if it's well-formed (which is the only thing `XDocument.Load()` should do, AFAIK).

About validation against an arbitrary schema: there is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954.aspx) which *adds* an overload of `Validate()` where you can specify another schema. Unfortunately for some obscure reasons the line number information are lost. You can however perform validation during reading. First of all define schema you want to use:

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlSchema)));
```

Then create a `XmlReaderSettings` to apply your schema:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas = schemas;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) => 
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Exception.LineNumber}: {e.Message}");
```

Then load the document, it will have the required information:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
|
```

Comment: This works too, but the problem is that if I validate like this, the LineNumber property returns always 0, and I'm using the SetLineInfo LoadOptions but does not work.

Comment: Let me understand, you load using Load(..., LoadOptions.SetLineInfo) and validating with Validate(...) the line number is always 0?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Turns out the schema adding/deleting is not needed at all.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean. Well, just move validation during loading. Updating answer.